# jQuery each on li tag get value based on data-job condition

Tags: jquery

I have ul list which has n records of user, i want to save those records which has data-job value as vk into array
html code is

```
<ul id="ulUsers">
<li data-job='sc' >Dev</li>
<li data-job='bk' >Pete</li>
<li data-job='sc' >Juli</li>
<li data-job='vk' >Rakx</li>
<li data-job='vk' >Meth</li>
<li data-job='sc' >Ajx</li>
<li data-job='bk' >Anov</li>
<li data-job='sc' >Juli</li>
<li data-job='sc' >Jade</li>
...
...
100+ row
<ul>
```

I tired it gives all record, how to get row based on data-job property

```
$("#ulUsers li").each(function(){
    
    console.log($(this).text());
    arr.push($(this).text());
             
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$("#ulUsers li[data-job='vk']").each(function(){

    console.log($(this).text());
    arr.push($(this).text());

});
```